# How do I replicate this graph?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, plotly

[image: Red lines indicate performance gain, while blue lines indicate performance drop.]

X axis contains 80 different variables. The green dots represent performance. The red/blue lines denote the increase/decrease in performance respectively. I was thinking of a box plot/scatter plot, but what I need I think is a combination of the two. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a scatter plot where the dot represents performance and the red/blue lines are represented as yerr.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

y = [20, 30, 40] 
x = np.arange(0,len(y), 1) 

xlabel = ['airplane', 'apple', 'banana'] 
change = [-10,0,+3]

y_err,err_color = [],[]
for i in change: 
    if i < 0 : 
        y_err.append([[abs(i)],[0]])
        err_color.append(['blue'])
    else: 
        y_err.append([[0],[i]])
        err_color.append(['red'])

for i in range(len(x)):
    print(y_err[i])
    plt.errorbar(x[i], y[i], yerr = y_err[i], color = 'green',fmt='.',ecolor = 
         err_color[i]) 

plt.xticks(x, xlabel,rotation = 'vertical')
plt.show()
```